# Combining of Multiple columns in Where clause

Tags: sql-server

```
WHERE (K.PATH OR K.ITEM_NAME) LIKE '%File Delivery and Specialized Product Team (CSTART)%'
```

Is this a valid query for `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not valid and will produce the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'or'.

You should write it as:

```
WHERE 
    K.PATH LIKE '%File Delivery and Specialized Product Team (CSTART)%'
    OR K.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%File Delivery and Specialized Product Team (CSTART)%'
```